# Set applet width with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, applet

I want to set the width of an applet with the width of the div that he is in. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming applet has an id of "myApplet":

**Note:** This will only work if the `div` element's width is set directly on the element (not using a stylesheet)

```
var myApplet = document.getElementById("myApplet");
myApplet.width = myApplet.parentNode.style.width;
```

Comment: This will only work if the div has an explicit width set on a style directly applied to the element (not even through a CSS selector).

Comment: Hmm, the best option be to use a class to control just the width, and assign it to both the div and the applet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<applet id="foo" ...></applet>

...

var app = document.getElementById('foo');
app.width = app.parentNode.offsetWidth;
```